# Why SignalR connection pedirod is an array, not a single value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server?toc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Faspnet%2Fcore%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=aspnetcore-3.0

```
.withAutomaticReconnect([0, 3000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 30000])
//.withAutomaticReconnect([0, 2000, 10000, 30000]) The default intervals.
```

Why SignalR connection pedirod is an array, not a single value? such as

```
.withAutomaticReconnect(3000)
```

Comment: Because in addition to specifying the reconnect timers, the number of elements determine when it should stop trying to reconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reconnect-clients) article,

> Without any parameters, withAutomaticReconnect() configures the client
>   to wait 0, 2, 10, and 30 seconds respectively before trying each
>   reconnect attempt, stopping after four failed attempts.

When you override default, you should provide an array to how many times that needs to retry.